# How can a Silverlight application connect to an existing WCF service?

Tags: silverlight, wcf, wcf-ria-services

I have a WPF client that is attached to WCF endpoint on a very simple ISS application.  I would like connect a Silverlight application to the same WCF service.  I've read that I have to enable OData.  Is this still necessary in 4?  If so, how do I do it?  How do I actually connect the endpoints?  Do I need to use RIA services to facilitate the connection?  Can I use the same IIS application to provide both endpoints?

Thanks in advance for any help.  This one has me stumped.

**Edits:**

Below is the configuration for my WCF Service and my Silverlight Client.

WCF Server Configuration (obfuscated):

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service name="MyNamespace.Services.MyService">
            <endpoint contract="MyNamespace.ServiceContracts.IMyService"
                      address=""
                      binding="wsHttpBinding"
                      />
            <endpoint contract="MyNamespace.ServiceContracts.IMyService"
                      address="basic"
                      binding="basicHttpBinding"
                      />
            <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange"
                      address="mex"
                      binding="mexHttpBinding"
                      />
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Silverlight Client Side Configuration (obfuscated):

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="Binding.Secure" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
                <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>

        <endpoint name="MyServiceReferenceNamespace.MyService"
                  contract="MyServiceReferenceNamespace.IMyService"
                  address="https://www.mydomain.com/MyVirtualDirectory/MyContract.svc"
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="Binding.Secure"
                  />

</system.serviceModel>
```

(The names have been changed to protect my clients.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to enable OData; as long as the endpoint in your existing service uses a binding which is compatible with Silverlight (for example, BasicHttpBinding), the SL app will be able to consume it just as well as the WPF one. If the binding is not compatible, you can add a new endpoint to the service (yes, it can be in the same IIS application) which can be used by the SL application.

In your SL project, you can choose "Add Service Reference", and that will create a proxy in that project which knows how to "talk" to the WCF service.

Comment: When you add the service reference, there will be a file created in your SL application called ServiceReferences.ClientConfig, which is similar to what the app.config would do for configuring the client endpoints in the WPF application.

Comment: I'm getting security exceptions having to do with cross-domain access (or at least that's what it suggest the problem might be).  Is there some specific security I need to set up?  The XAP is being served by the same application that contains the WCF service.

Comment: The exception states that it "**could be** due to ... cross-domain", but not necessarily it. Take a look at the page at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470100(VS.95).aspx, which lists many steps you can take to debug such errors.

Comment: No luck.  I have a feeling it has something to do with my configuration.  I'll add my endpoint configurations above.

Comment: If you look at the request using something like Fiddler, do you see a 404 (Not Found) or a different error? If you see something else (such as 400 or 500), maybe the response itself will have some additional information. If it doesn't, then you can try enabling tracing at the service, and it should contain more information about the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that.  I do use the address "basic" to differentiate between my WS* and basic bindings.  Do I have to specify that address in any way on my client configuration?

Comment: At first I was getting 404 on clientaccesspolicy.xml and crossdomain.xml.  I realized that I was trying to connect my Silverlight client back to my WCF application itself.  I modified my client configuration to point to the hosting project instead and now I am getting "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error" in Fiddler.  I really do think it might have something to do with the "basic" address.

Comment: That was it.  When I take out the "basic" address and remove the "wsHttpBinding" from my configuration, it works fine. What do I have to do to specify that "basicHttpBinding" when I call the server?

Answer (score 1):

The best information is found on this MSDN article: [Accessing Web Services in Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296254%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

Is the Silverlight hosted on the same IIS as your WCF service? If not, you should read: [Making a Service Available Across Domains Boundaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

Comment: This was also very helpful.  Is it saying though that a WCF service has to be specially enabled to work with a Silverlight front end?  I've set up a cross-domain instance on the root of my service application.  I'm still getting security exceptions.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You can add a clientaccesspolicy.xml on the IIS hosting the WCF service.